# What is the most efficient algorithm for solving the cell-sum puzzle?

Tags: algorithm

The cell-sum puzzle is defined as follows:

Given two sets of non-negative integers **X** = {*x*<sub>1</sub>, *x*<sub>2</sub>,...,*x*<sub>m</sub>} and **Y** = {*y*<sub>1</sub>, *y*<sub>2</sub>,...,*y*<sub>n</sub>}, fill each cell in a grid of *m* rows and *n* columns with a single non-negative integer such that *x*<sub>i</sub> is the sum of the cells in the *i*th row for every *i* ≤ *m* and such that *y*<sub>j</sub> is the sum of the cells in the *j*th column for every *j* ≤ *n*.

For example, if **X** = {7, 13} and **Y** = {8, 9, 3}, then your goal would be to replace the question marks in the following grid:

```
? + ? + ? = 7
+   +   +
? + ? + ? = 13
=   =   =
8   9   3
```

and a valid solution would be:

```
3 + 1 + 3 = 7
+   +   +
5 + 8 + 0 = 13
=   =   =
8   9   3
```

How do you solve this puzzle for arbitrarily large *m* and *n*? Also, for your method of choice, do you know the time complexity, and can you tell whether it is the most efficient algorithm possible?

Comment: This essentially sounds like the game of [Kakuro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakuro).

Comment: 1) Look into dynamic programming. You are going to start by solving this for 1x1 and expand your solution accordingly adding rows and columns one by one (technically narrow it down to 1x1 from mxn recursively)

2) This is better suited for https://cs.stackexchange.com/

3) We are not here to do your homework for you. If you need help, you are going to have to show at least some attempt at solving the problem. What approaches you tried and why they have failed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a linear-time algorithm (O(m + n) assuming we can output a sparse matrix, which is asymptotically optimal because we have to read the whole input; otherwise O(m n), which is optimal because we have to write the whole output).

Fill in the upper-left question mark with the min of the first row sum and the first column sum. If the first row sum equals the min, put zeros in the rest of the row. If the first column sum equals the min, put zeros in the rest of the column. Extract the subproblem by subtracting the new value from the first row/column if they remain and recurse.

On your example:

```
? + ? + ? = 7
+   +   +
? + ? + ? = 13
=   =   =
8   9   3
```

Min of 7 and 8 is 7.

```
7 + 0 + 0 = 7
+   +   +
? + ? + ? = 13
=   =   =
8   9   3
```

Extract the subproblem.

```
? + ? + ? = 13
=   =   =
1   9   3
```

Min of 13 and 1 is 1.

```
1 + ? + ? = 13
=   =   =
1   9   3
```

Extract the subproblem.

```
? + ? = 12
=   =
9   3
```

Keep going until we get the final solution.

```
7 + 0 + 0 = 7
+   +   +
1 + 9 + 3 = 13
=   =   =
8   9   3
```

Comment: Apologies, it looks like I made a mistake. Here's my corrected attempt: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBJhb.png

Comment: How can it be O(m + n) when the output size is mn?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Not sure what the initial comment was, but yes, there can be multiple correct solutions.

Comment: You certainly think of it already, but it is worth mentioning that a simple mathematical demonstration can be provided, to prove the validity of your greedy algorithm. As a consequence, this proves that all such well-formed puzzles have at least one solution.

Comment: @HeapOverflow I think the idea is that since each iteration fills either a whole row or a whole column with just one non-zero entry, then you can produce the output as a sparse matrix in linear time.

Comment: @kaya3 Ok, if the output specification allows that, you can do that, but I wouldn't describe that with *"put zeros in the rest of the row"* (and not mention sparse matrices).

Comment: @HeapOverflow Indeed.

Comment: @vivek_23 my initial comment was a screenshot with an ill-formed attempt which I thought was demonstrating why his algorithm did not work in the general case. I made a mistake in my attempt, so I retracted the statement.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: the problem is not NP-hard. The algorithm in David Eisenstat's answer is [provably correct](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1969567/732230) for finding a solution. However, I'll leave this answer here since it gives a way to find *all* solutions, which might be of interest to some.

---

For what it's worth, my "method of choice" is [constraint programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_programming); it's easy to model this as a [constraint satisfaction problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem), and then a wide range of well-developed algorithms can be applied. The code below is in Python, using the [python-constraint](https://labix.org/python-constraint) library.

```py
x_sums = [7, 13]
y_sums = [8, 9, 3]

from constraint import *

problem = Problem()

x_n, y_n = len(x_sums), len(y_sums)
max_num = max(x_sums + y_sums)
problem.addVariables(range(x_n * y_n), range(max_num + 1))

for i, x in enumerate(x_sums):
    v = [ i + x_n * j for j in range(y_n) ]
    problem.addConstraint(ExactSumConstraint(x), v)

for j, y in enumerate(y_sums):
    v = [ i + x_n * j for i in range(x_n) ]
    problem.addConstraint(ExactSumConstraint(y), v)

solution = problem.getSolution()
for i in range(x_n):
    print(*( solution[i + x_n * j] for j in range(y_n) ))
```

Output: it finds a different solution to yours. Alternatively, you could search for all solutions; there are 26 of them.

```
4 0 3
4 9 0
```

The time complexity of this is hard to pin down exactly; as a very weak upper bound we can say it's definitely at most O(`max_num ** (x_n * y_n)`) since that's the size of the search space. In practice it is much better than that, but the algorithm this library uses is rather complicated and difficult to analyse precisely. It's a [backtracking search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking), but with some clever ways of using the constraints to eliminate the vast majority of branches from the search tree.

For some idea of how deep this rabbit hole goes, the [*Handbook of Constraint Programming*](https://dl.acm.org/doi/book/10.5555/2843512) gives a lot of details about techniques that constraint-solving algorithms can use to improve efficiency.

Comment: Please note that it is easy to formally prove that David Eisenstat's algorithm is correct!

Comment: I don't think I could trust the [paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-78275-9_32) you originally mentioned. They say they prove a problem NP-hard by reducing it to another problem.